# Java regular expression to get a portion of a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to get a portion of string that contains one of the targeted words. For example, from the following example string:

```
...
def a:
...
target1
...
def b:
...
def c:
...
```

I want to get this part:

```
def a:
...
target1
...
```

Here is my Java code:

```
s = "(def\\W(.*)\\W(target1|target2|target3)\\W(.*)def\\W)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

The problem is that it does not find out anything.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: And your question? What's the problem with your code so far?

Comment: @tnw Right now the code does not print out anything.

Comment: @Ryan .. I am not sure if this will work for you but can you try something like "(def.*(target1|target2|target3))"

Comment: Are you trying to find _targets_ from one def to the next def? I assume that means no _def_ in between right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
  "(\\bdef\\s((?!\\bdef\\b).)*?\\b(?:target1|target2|target3)\\b.*?(?=sdef))",
  Pattern.DOTALL);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX3rX1/5)

Comment: thanks a lot. It looks great, only have one problem now. if the input is the following, it maps multiple "def". 
...
def b:
...
def a:
...
target1
...
def b:
...
def c:
...

Answer (score 1):

By default `.` represents any character *expect line separators*. To make dot accept all character add `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s,Pattern.DOTALL);
```

You may also want to make `.*` reluctant with `.*?`.

You can use regex like

```
String s = "(def\\W(.*?)\\W(target1|target2|target3)\\W(.*?))def\\W";
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - group 1
```

and inside loop use `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group(0)`

Comment: thanks! I made some progress with your solution. Right now, there is another problem. the "def" gets mapped multiple times now. Anywhy I can restrict "def" occurs twice only?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
 #  "(?ms)^def\\b(?:(?!^def\\b).)*?\\b(target[123])\\b(?:(?!^def\\b).)*"

 (?ms)                         # Multi-line and Dot-all modes
 ^ def \b                      # 'def'
 (?:
      (?! ^ def \b )                # Not 'def' 
      . 
 )*?
 \b 
 ( target [123] )              # (1), 'target 1 or 2 or 3
 \b 
 (?:
      (?! ^ def \b )                # Not 'def' 
      . 
 )*
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 27 ) 
def a:
...
target1
...

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 13 , len 7 ) 
target1
```